# Inequality Induction Proof, how should I proceed?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I have been trying to prove inequalities using induction to no avail.

For example,

Prove the following:
$\frac{1}{2^{1}}+\frac{2}{2^{2}}+\frac{3}{2^{3}}+...+\frac{n}{2^{n}}<2$

Base Case:

$\frac{1}{2^{1}} = 2$

$\frac{1}{2}<2\;$  Which is true.

We assume, for n=k, that

$\frac{1}{2^{1}}+\frac{2}{2^{2}}+\frac{3}{2^{3}}+...+\frac{k}{2^{k}}<2\;\;\;$ is true.

As induction step with n=k+1, we need to prove that

$\frac{1}{2^{1}}+\frac{2}{2^{2}}+\frac{3}{2^{3}}+...+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}<2\;\;\;$

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: You can't proceed since you don't know the difference between $2$ and the sum of the first $k$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

A case can be made that this response is defective, because I am abandoning the OP's approach, which I consider the wrong approach for this problem.  This is a classic geometric series problem where (for $0 < t < 1$) you have

$$S = t + t^2 + t^3 + \cdots = t \times \frac{1}{1-t}$$

and

$$T = t + 2t^2 + 3t^3 + \cdots =
S(1 + t + t^2 + \cdots) =
t \times \left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

You may first prove the following equality:

> Prove that $\frac 1 {2^1} + \frac 2 {2^2} + \dots + \frac k {2^k} = 2 - \frac {k + 2} {2^k}$.

This can be proved by induction on $k$ (easy exercise).

Once it is proved, the original inequality follows.

Comment: Beat me to it! Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to prove it with induction, which was the goal.

I followed the suggestion to prove that  $\;\frac{1}{2^{1}}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{2^{3}}+...+\frac{k}{2^{k}} = 2-\frac{k+2}{2^{k}}\;$

for k+1 we have that

$\;\frac{1}{2^{1}}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{2^{3}}+...+\frac{k}{2^{k}}+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} =   2-\frac{k+3}{2^{k+1}}\;$

It follows from the inductive hypothesis that

$2-\frac{k+2}{2^{k}}+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} = 2-\frac{k+3}{2^{k+1}}\;$

$2-\frac{2k+4}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}} = 2-\frac{k+3}{2^{k+1}}\;$

$2+\frac{-3-k}{2^{k+1}} = 2-\frac{k+3}{2^{k+1}}\;$

$2-\frac{k+3}{2^{k+1}} = 2-\frac{k+3}{2^{k+1}}\;$

Which verifies that $\;\frac{1}{2^{1}}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{2^{3}}+...+\frac{k}{2^{k}}$ is 2 minus something else, which in turn means that it is less than 2 thus proving the original statement.